# Confusion with the way Redux selector is used

Tags: redux, reselect

I was learning Redux and came across the concept of Redux selector. I got curious what that was and found out that it is a function that encapsulates the logic of slice of store state so that we can reuse it. Here is the code:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    incompleteTodos: state.todos.filter((todo) => {
      return !todo.completed
    });
  }
}
```

Becomes

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    incompleteTodos: getIncompleteTodos(state)
  };
}
```

But the question I wanted to ask is that Is it true that when we use selector like this incompleteTodos: getIncompleteTodos(state) apart from **reusability** we also get **memoization** by default. Thus, we do not need to use reselect library. Is that true?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer your question is No. By default properties in mapStateToProps is calculated every time when the component is updated, but there is some other solutions:

1. Reselect library which you mention, it's official package of Redux team so you can trust it.
2. You can use Redux Toolkit package which is also an official library and out of the box it also has Reselect.
3. You can use Redux Hook - useSelector which by default behaves like memorized property, so i guess this is what you are interested, in terms of default memorization.